# Push spliced array to empty array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I want to iterate over an array and consecutively push them into another array after adding the first n numbers:

```
let arr = []
let iniArr = [...Array(9).keys()].map(item=>1)
let push = iniArr.slice(0,3).reduce((total,num)=>total+num)

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  iniArr.splice(i,3)
  iniArr.splice(i,0,push)
  arr.push(iniArr)  
  }
```

I don't get what is expected but the final result of the whole iteration for each push:

```
(3) [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]
0: (3) [3, 3, 3]
1: (3) [3, 3, 3]
2: (3) [3, 3, 3]
```

However if I console.log them I get back the results I want in the array:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  iniArr.splice(i,3)
  iniArr.splice(i,0,push)
  console.log(iniArr)    
}

(7) [3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
(5) [3, 3, 1, 1, 1]
(3) [3, 3, 3]
```

Can someone explain why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

I have to use spread syntanx,

```
arr.push([...iniArr]) 
//instead of
arr.push(iniArr)
```

but I still don't get why.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing the reference of `iniArr` 3 times to the `arr`, and any time the `iniArr` data changes, the `arr` respectfully display that.

As you find out, when you pass the values of the `iniArr` like `[...iniArr]` and these values are primitive(like numbers that you are using here), so they push to the  `arr` with their values, and not changing, no matter what happened to the `iniArr`